# Dynamic connections classes

Tags: php, object-oriented, mysqli, dependency-injection

I have an abstract `Connection` class which looks like this:

```
abstract class Connection
{

    /**
     * @var mixed $instance Represents the instance of the connection
     */
    protected $instance = null;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getInstance() {
        if (!$this->isInitialized()) {
            echo "Cant get instance yet because the connection isn't open";
        }
        return $this->instance;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isInitialized() {
        return $this->instance !== null;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the connection
     */
    public abstract function initialize();

    /**
     * Closes the connection
     */
    public abstract function terminate();
}
```

It requires an `intialize()` and `terminate()`in its childs or subchilds.

- The initialize method opens the connection
- The terminate method closes the connection

The `$instance` determinates the object which has to be ran to start the `Connection`. For example, for a MySQL connection, this could be the `mysqli` object with its parameters.

---

A child class of the abstract `Connection` class looks like this (in this case im only showing a Connection to a database).

This class cannot be instantiated because its also abstract.

```
abstract class DatabaseConnection extends Connection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $host;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $database;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $credentials = [];

    /**
     * @param float  $host
     * @param string $database
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param array  $credentials
     */
    public function __construct($host, $database, $username, $password, $credentials = []) {
        $this->host        = $host;
        $this->database    = $database;
        $this->username    = $username;
        $this->password    = $password;
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
    }

    public final function initialize() {
        if ($this->isInitialized()) {
            throw new Exception("Database connection isnt open yet.");
        }
        $this->instance = $this->getConnectionObject();
    }

    public final function terminate() {
        if ($this->isInitialized()) {
            throw new Exception("Database is closed");
        }
        $this->instance = null;
    }

    protected abstract function getConnectionObject();
}
```

This mostly speaks for itself, you initialize the credentials in the `__construct` method.

The `getConnectionObject()` determinates the object wich has to be instantiated to initialize a Database Connection.

---

A child class of the `DatabaseConnection` looks like this:

```
class MySQLConnection extends DatabaseConnection
{

    /**
     * @return mysqli
     */
    public function getConnectionObject() {
        return new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
    }
}
```

This can be instantiated, to use this, i need to use the following code:

```
$connection = new MySQLConnection('127.0.0.1', 'db', 'username' 'password');
```

To open the connection you use the following method:

```
$connection->initialize();
```

To close the connection you use the following method:

```
$connection->terminate();
```

---

To give this `DatabaseConnection` functionality I call  the `getInstance()` method on the `$connection` object i've just made.

```
$connection->getInstance();
```

In this case this returns the `mysqli` object, from here i can call all needed functions.

---

A few notes:

- This is for practice, i was trying to create a connection class wich had support for multiple types of connections.
- What I originally wanted was to seperate each database function in a seperate class, but i did not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a major issue. It's breaking a basic rule of inheritance. The *"base"* class (`Connection`) does not specify a constructor. That is to say, any constructors that a child class may contain should take either *no*, or only *optional* arguments. That's what the Liskov principle states anyway.

Your `DatabaseConnection` extends `Connection` (BTW: an abstract extending an abstract... that smells, if you ask me), but it defines a constructor with *non-optional* arguments. This contradicts, and breaks the inherited contract defined by `Connection`.
PHP historically, has been very forgiving when it came to conflicting signatures, especially in the constructors, but as the manual says:

> When inheriting from an abstract class, all methods marked abstract in the parent's class declaration must be defined by the child; additionally, these methods must be defined with the same (or a less restricted) visibility. For example, if the abstract method is defined as protected, the function implementation must be defined as either protected or public, but not private. Furthermore the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same. For example, if the child class defines an optional argument, where the abstract method's signature does not, there is no conflict in the signature. ***This also applies to constructors as of PHP 5.4. Before 5.4 constructor signatures could differ.***

That ship has sailed. Now in case you're wondering why this is such a big deal, look at the code below:

```
function checkConnection(Connection $con)
{//type-hint ensures instance of Connection is passed
    //for some reason, create a copy:
    $class = get_class($con);//get actual class
    $newInstance = new $class();//<-- No arguments!!
}
```

Now this function **has** to be allowed to assume that no arguments need to be passed to a constructor, if there even is a constructor. Simply because this function is hinting at `Connection`  instances. Because of the type-hint, the function can only assume the methods/properties that are declared by the `Connection` class are available, and that the instance that it is being passed is an instance (an extension) of this contract. `Connection` doesn't declare a constructor, so its children can only create a public, optional constructor.

Fix this issue ASAP.
Apart from that, I'd really like to see where you're going with this, because this `abstract class Connection` + `abstract class DatabaseConnection` seems like an awful lot of abstraction for what will, essentially, be a service locator, or DI container.

A DI Container, or SL shouldn't even care what kind of dependencies/services/objects it is injecting and instantiating. So there's even less need of these abstractions you've written from that perspective.

I'm also having doubts concerning the `terminate` method. If a piece of code uses a `mysqli` connection, and needs the connection to be open for some reason (ie: a prepared statement that is pending, a huge result set is being fetched in chunks,...), having the connections managed at a central level might cause conflicts. I'd say that the only place where the container can close connections is when it is being destroyed: if the container is going out of scope, all that it has spawned is probably gone, too.

---

*Update - A crude example of a container:*

Say you have config files, that define DB connections, which could look like this;

```
connections:
    db:
        readConnection:
            class: mysqli
            host: 127.0.0.1
            database: db
            username: user
            password: pass
        writeConnection:
            class: PDO
            host: 8.8.8.8
            database: db
            username: user
            password: pass
```

Now, a container would parse this config, and allow you to write something like this:

```
$mysqli = $container->get('connections.db.readConnection');
```

This `get` method would then parse the slug, and interpret the configuration it finds, to end up returning:

```
$path = explode('.', $slug);
$section = $this->getFullConfig();
foreach ($path as $key)
    $section = $section->get($key);
$class = $section->get('class');
return new $class(
    $section->get('host'),
    $section->get('database'),
    $section->get('username'),
    $section->get('password')
);
```

Note that this is a grossly oversimplified, but you get the idea.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, but thanks for your time and answer. What do you mean by an Dependency Injection Container? I've heard of it but dont know how to use it. Can you please show some code examples? And would it be better to use an interface instead of the abstract `Connection` class?

Comment: @Bas: It would be better _not_ to use a `Connection` abstract class, or interface. Connections in PHP are more like resources, than they are objects (By that I mean: you use a connection as-is, it doesn't have an API as such). Look at most frameworks being used today, the vast majority have containers, or injection components

Comment: so it would be better to leave the databaseconnection abstract without extending or implementing anything?

Comment: @bas: imho, creating an abstract db connection wrapper is really rather pointless, without also writing an entire DBAL, like doctrine does. Just check my reviews of PDO abstraction/wrapper classes as to why I say this

Comment: this is really getting to comiclicated for me at the moment.. This was my whole idea to have support for multiple connections types, in different files?

Comment: @Bas: PHP doesn't have a _connection-type_ as such. A socket, a file handle (or stream), a buffer, heck, even DB connections or child processes (created through `proc_open`), they're all **resources**, but they're very much different things. You wouldn't dream of creating a child of your `Connection`  class to wrap around a file handle, or a process started with `proc_open`, would you?

Comment: The basic issue is this: If you're able to write a ***useful*** abstraction layer that can handle _all_ types of resources, then by all means, go for it. But what you seem to be doing is writing an abstraction layer that sort of creates an API for certain resource types that may or may not connect to external services. By that logic, wouldn't your `Connection` class be equipped to deal with (s)FTP connections, curl requests that are reused several times,...? A decent abstraction layer (for example DBAL) is type-agnostic (MySQL,MSSQL,pg, doesn't matter). abstracting all resources is impossible

Comment: Actually, that was my plan. To deal with all types of connections coming from the base `Connection` class. Is this a bad thing or ami doing it wrong?

Comment: @Bas: I know what you're trying to do, but it is, I'm afraid, not a good idea. PHP doesn't expose actual connections. The variables that hold a _"connection"_ are _resources_. A DB connection is a resource, just like a pipe, a socket, or a file handle is. Resources are a distinct type, [cf the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), in particular [the `get_resource_type` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php)

Comment: What is commonly referred to as a DB connection is actually a link (a binding from PHP to an external DB adapter). The connection is managed for you. Because you can't really manage the connection in full, you don't have the tools available to write a complete, and useful abstraction layer to handle any type of connection/link resource. You'll get what I mean when you try to write an abstract `Connection` class that can be used for both DB links as `proc_open` pipes... If you want, give it a go, but trust me, you'll soon find out it can't be done reliably

Comment: The closest you'll be able to get is to write a class that looks like this: `abstract class Connection { protected $resource = null; }` and create a bunch of children for each type of resource, which defeats the point of having a unifying `Connection` class, really

Answer (score 1):

It looks reasonably well thought out to me, although I am not sure how much it would be used beyond practice.

There are a few small things that can be improved. Comments are inline

```
public final function terminate() {
    // ### Is this test correct, if I terminate after initialization I always get an exception?
    if ($this->isInitialized()) {
        throw new Exception("Database is closed");
    }
    $this->instance = null;
}


// ### You can typehint array here to throw a warning if an array is not supplied
public function __construct($host, $database, $username, $password, array $credentials = array()) {
    $this->host        = $host;
    $this->database    = $database;
    $this->username    = $username;
    $this->password    = $password;
    $this->credentials = $credentials;
}


// ### It would be simple to automatically initialize a connection
public function getInstance() {
    if (!$this->isInitialized()) {
        $this->initialize();
    }
    return $this->instance;
}


// ### Is this going to be overridden in practice, if not make it private
public function isInitialized() {
    return $this->instance !== null;
}


// ### If you are going to throw exceptions it might be a good idea to subclass them
// ### So you could throw a ConnectionException for example, this would make it   
// ### easier to catch Connection specific errors
public final function initialize() {
    if ($this->isInitialized()) {
        throw new Exception("Database connection isnt open yet.");
    }
    $this->instance = $this->getConnectionObject();
}
```

Comment: I'm  sorry I took so long to answer. But thanks for your answer and time. I see that i've made a small mistake there indeed at the `terminate()` method, thanks for pointing that out. What do you mean by this line in at the `getInstance` function though?  `// ### It would be simple to automatically initialize a connection`

Comment: The way it was coded you call getInstance, then have to call initialize(), then use the object. I was just suggesting you could call getInstance and if it wasn't initialize then initialize a connection then return it

Comment: Could you edit your post how you would use it then?